# Best Strategy and Expectation. Probability Theory.

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we roll a die, repeatedly if we like, and sum. We can stop at any point, and the sum becomes our score; however, if  we exceed 50, our score is zero.

What should our strategy be to maximize the expected value of our score? What is the expected score with this optimal strategy?

Now, intuitively, the strategy should be: stop after our score exceeds 44. However, I have no clue how to calculate the expectation. It should involve induction but I don't know how to execute this at all.

Please help!

Comment: Say you are at $45$.  Then you have a $\frac 16$ chance of a profit/loss of each of $\{1,2,3,4,5,-50\}$. That is an expected loss of $-5.8333\cdots$ so you should stop.

Comment: @lulu That definitely explains 44. But how to calculate the overall expected score under this strategy?

Comment: To get that, work recursively.  For $n≤45$ the probability of reaching $n$, call it $P(n)$, is clearly $P(n)=\frac 16\times (P(n-1)+P(n-2)+\cdots +P(n-6))$.  For $45<n≤50$ you have to truncate that sum (as you can't get from $47$ to $50$, say, under optimal play).

Comment: @lulu Oh! I know the idea now! I'm gonna keep studying probability theory in summer. BTW, You also helped out my previous post. You're like a god to me.

Comment: This method is known in dynamic programming as *backward induction*.

Comment: @Math1000 I read that in the syllabus of my algorithm class in the coming fall quarter. So that's what dynamic programming is!

Comment: Note:  I made an error in my first comment.  The loss should have been $45$, not $50$.   That makes the expectation a loss of $-5$, so the conclusion is unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have decided that your strategy is to roll on $44$ or less and stop on $45$ or more you just need to compute the probability of reaching each number $45-50$.  Excel makes this easy.  Make a column $n$ with $0$ to $50$ and five blank lines above $0$.  The next column will hold the probability of reaching $n$.  You start with $1$ for reaching $0$.  For each number $1$ to $45$ you have the probability is $\frac 16$ the sum of the six lines above because you can get there from each of those numbers with the proper roll.  It turns out the probabilities have almost stabilized at $\frac 27$ for each number reflecting the fact that the average roll is $\frac 72$.  Above $45$ the sum has to have a smaller range because you quit above $44$.  This gives you the chance you stop at each number.  Now multiply each number by its probability and add.  The result is just about $46\frac 23$.  The bottom of my spreadsheet is below with the expected value calculation next to these columns.
[image]